# Find specific Row of Data from Pandas Dataframe in While Loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

1. I am trying to take a csv, and read it as a Pandas Dataframe.
2. This Dataframe contains 4 rows of numbers.
3. I want to pick a specific row of data from the Dataframe.
4. In a While Loop, I want to select a random row from the Dataframe, and compare it to row that I picked.
5. I want it to continue to run through the while loop until that random row, is 100% equal to the row I picked prior.
6. Then I want the While Loop to break and I want it to have counted how many tries it took to match the random number.

Here's what I have so far:

This is an example of the Dataframe:

```
    A  B  C  D
1   2  7  12 14
2   4  5  11 23
3   4  6  14 20
4   4  7  13 50
5   9  6  14 35
```

Here is an example of my efforts:

```
import time
import pandas as pd

then = time.time()

count = 0

df = pd.read_csv('Get_Numbers.csv')
df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

while True:
    df_elements = df.sample(n=1)
    random_row = df_elements
    print(random_row)
    find_this_row = df['A','B','C','D' == '4','7','13,'50']
    print(find_this_row)
    if find_this_row != random_row:
        count += 1
    else:
        break

print("You found the correct numbers! And it only took " + str(count) + " tries to get there! Your numbers were: " + str(find_this_row))

now = time.time()

print("It took: ", now-then, " seconds")
```

The above code gives an obvious error... but I have tried so many different versions now of finding the `find_this_row` numbers that I just don't know what to do anymore, so I left this attempt in.

What I would like to try to avoid is using the specific index for the row I am trying to find, I would rather use just the values to find this.

I am using `df_elements = df.sample(n=1)` to select a row at random. This was to avoid using `random.choice` as I was not sure if that would work or which way is more time/memory efficient, but I'm open to advice on that as well.

In my mind it seems simple, randomly select a row of data, if it doesn't match the row of data that I want, keep randomly selecting rows of data until it does match. But I can't seem to execute it.

Any help is EXTREMELY Appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to sample from the DataFrame with replacement or without replacement? (could tries exceed the number of rows of your DataFrame, for instance)

Comment: Yes, I would like the tries to be able to exceed the number of rows in my Dataframe. I'm reading your answer from below. It's definitely using somethings I'm not familiar with (I'm still a big beginner in my mind) but it seems to be getting the results that I was gearing towards!

Comment: my apologies, I was trying to solve a problem that wasn't there. I added a solution to your actual problem, and then how you might think about doing this in less of a looped fashion if timing were ever an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use values which returns `np.ndarray` of `shape=(1, 2)`, use `values[0]` to get just 1D array.

Then compare the arrays with `any()`

```
import time
import pandas as pd

then = time.time()

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [1, 2, 3],
                        'B': [8, 9, 10]})

find_this_row = [2, 9]
print("Looking for: {}".format(find_this_row))

count = 0
while True:
    random_row = df.sample(n=1).values[0]
    print(random_row)

    if any(find_this_row != random_row):
        count += 1
    else:
        break

print("You found the correct numbers! And it only took " + str(count) + " tries to get there! Your numbers were: " + str(find_this_row))

now = time.time()

print("It took: ", now-then, " seconds")
```

Comment: Thank you for this response, It was a toss up between your answer and the answer from ALollz. They both worked for me for what I'm trying to do!

Answer (score 1):

How about using `values`?

`values` will return you a list of values. And then you can compare two lists easily.

`list1 == list2` will return an array of `True` and `False` values as it compares indexes of the corresponding lists. You can check if all of the values returned are `True`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that tests one row at a time. We check if the `values` of the chosen row are equal to the values of the sampled `DataFrame`. We require that they `all` match.

```
row = df.sample(1)

counter = 0
not_a_match = True

while not_a_match:
    not_a_match = ~(df.sample(n=1).values == row.values).all()
    counter+=1

print(f'It took {counter} tries and the numbers were\n{row}')
#It took 9 tries and the numbers were
#   A  B   C   D
#4  4  7  13  50
```

---

If you want to get a little bit faster, you select one row and then sample the `DataFrame` with replacement many times. You can then check for the first time the sampled row equals your sampled `DataFrame`, giving you how many 'tries' it would have taken in a while loop, but in much less time. The loop protects against the unlikely case we do not find a match, given that it's sampling with replacement.

```
row = df.sample(1)

n = 0
none_match = True
k = 10  # Increase to check more matches at once.

while none_match:
    matches = (df.sample(n=len(df)*k, replace=True).values == row.values).all(1)
    none_match = ~matches.any()  # Determine if none still match
    n += k*len(df)*none_match  # Only increment if none match
n = n + matches.argmax() + 1

print(f'It took {n} tries and the numbers were\n{row}')
#It took 3 tries and the numbers were
#   A  B   C   D
#4  4  7  13  50
```

Comment: Thank you! This got me up an running! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of hints first. This line does not work for me:

```
find_this_row = df['A','B','C','D' == '4','7','13,'50']
```

For 2 reasons:

- a missing " ' " after ,'13
- df is a DataFrame(), so using keys like below is not supported

> df['A','B','C','D' ...

Either use keys to return a DataFrame():

```
df[['A','B','C','D']]
```

or as a Series():

```
df['A']
```

Since you need the whole row with multiple columns do this:

```
df2.iloc[4].values
```

> array(['4', '7', '13', '50'], dtype=object)

Do the same with your sample row:

```
df2.sample(n=1).values
```

Comparison between rows needs to be done for all() elements/columns:

```
df2.sample(n=1).values == df2.iloc[4].values
```

> array([[ True, False, False, False]])

with adding .all() like the following:

```
(df2.sample(n=1).values == df2.iloc[4].values).all()
```

which returns

> True/False

All together:

```
import time
import pandas as pd

then = time.time()
count = 0
while True:
    random_row = df2.sample(n=1).values
    find_this_row = df2.iloc[4].values
    if (random_row == find_this_row).all() == False:
        count += 1
    else:
        break

print("You found the correct numbers! And it only took " + str(count) + " tries to get there! Your numbers were: " + str(find_this_row))

now = time.time()

print("It took: ", now-then, " seconds")
```