# Python Randomly Select Rows Until Criteria is Met

Tags: python, pandas, random, sample

I have a dataframe that has a few ID's and then a column for money like this,

```
Id1     Id2     Id3     Money
1       10      13      10000
2       15      12      12500
3       20      11      60000
```

I need a script to randomly select rows until I hit $80M in money. I'm assuming a while loop such as...

```
while sum(money) < 80000000:
    df.sample()
```

Comment: You don't _need_ a pythonic method, it would just be desirable. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you want to be able to sample the same row more than once?

Comment: There was a similar question asked a few hours ago about [finding matches with random sampling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53000259/find-specific-row-of-data-from-pandas-dataframe-in-while-loop). You could imagine just modifying to instead check for a sum, instead of things being equal.

Comment: @user3483203 no, rows should not be duplicated!

Comment: @roganjosh I've tried using the pandas sample method with a while loop, however the process continues to return the original data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perhaps rephrase your question a bit, it seems that you're looking for a random sample of rows such that the sum of `Money` is < 80000000.  One way to do that would be to use `.sample()` to do shuffling, combined with `.cumsum()`:

```
>>> reordered = df.sample(n=df.shape[0])
>>> lim = reordered[reordered.Money.cumsum() < 80000000]
```

This will sample without replacement.

This is perhaps not the most memory-efficient in comparison to taking rows one-by-one, but should do the trick for something of a reasonable size.

Comment: Ha, your edit beat my comment :) I don't think there's a pandas-onic way of doing it

Comment: Though given their example, it seems like there will definitely need to be replacement, and then the question is do you chance it without a while loop :D

Comment: @Brad Solomon I think this is right there... an issue I'm running into is this method not being able to use a boolean on ints and strings. One of my IDs looks something like 'bng78' so it cannot be converted to an int

Comment: @jchristensen912 I’m not sure if I’m understanding, what’s the exception on the traceback?